# Как подключить USB drive к Debian?

Tags: unix, debian, linux

Поставил `Debian` с маленькой инсталляции (280 мб). Пытаюсь подключить USB флэшку. Подключаю-вынимаю флэшку и выполняю команды *dmesg | tail* и смотрю *var/log/messages*, однако там никаких записей не появляется. 
При этом в *var/log/messages* при загрузке ОС пишутся слова про USB: *"new full-speed usb device ..."*.

*fdisk -l* выдает 3 строки:

```
*dev/sda1 (...) System=Linux
dev/sda2 (...) System=Extended
dev/sda5 (...) System=Linux swap/Solaris*
```

Что я не сделал, где смотреть?

`Debian 7.1`, `VirtualBox` на винде, сам `VirtualBox` флэшки видит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось, что в `VirtualBox` надо не просто подключать `USB`, но и вручную добавлять все флэшки. Это и было причиной, далее обычный `mount` сработал.

Answer (score 2):

Я могу ошибаться, но монтированием съемных носителей может заниматься `GUI`, поэтому прописывание монтирования таковых в `/etc/fstab` излишне и может только помешать. Поэтому проверьте `/etc/fstab` и закомментируйте строку/-и с таким носителем. Не закомментируйте лишнего!

Если же у Вас иксы не установлены, тогда попробуйте сделать так:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

и вставить Вашу флешку.

Посмотрите, запущен ли демон для `USB`-устройств - `usbd` вроде.
Попробуйте перезагрузиться со вставленной флешкой и посмотреть логи с момента загрузки.
Если выдача по команде Выше покажет присвоенный номер диска - например sdb1 - примонтируйте его стандартными средствами.

Comment: GUI у меня нету. В том-то и дело, я втыкал-вынимал флешку и не увидел какой-либо активности в var/log/messages.

Comment: Какие еще могу предложить/предположить варианты:
1. Как уже сказал - перезагрузиться со вставленной флешкой;
2. Проверить флешку на других машинах, на обсуждаемой - на разных портах и другую флешку на ней же. Лучше подключайте к корневым концентраторам на задней стенке системника и не используйте пока хабы и удлинители;
3. выполните от root-а lsusb -v и запостите сюда вывод (если это технически возможно, не знаю).

Comment: заработало, оказалось недонастроил VirtualBox, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
```